# Define a color function based on color samples obtained from ColorBrewer

Tags: plotting, color

I am quite new to *Mathematica* and I am searching for a way to create a smooth colormap based on the samples given by [ColorBrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/).
Is it possible to create a interpolated function from those sample points?

Comment: By samples, do you mean color samples, i.e, color schemes?

Comment: yes, as you can see on the website there are only color samples (e.g. 6 rgb values)

Comment: Look up `Blend[]`...

Comment: How do you want to use your color map in _Mathematica_? How you incorporate your six RGB values into `Blend` will depend on you intended use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I enter RGB values in a matrix using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> ([tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EnteringTablesAndMatrices.html)):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> ```
> {{237, 248, 177}, {127, 205, 187}, {44, 127, 184}}
> ```

Then create a color function `cf`:

```
With[{rgb = RGBColor @@@ (dat/255)},
 cf = Blend[rgb, #] &;
]
```

And use it:

```
ArrayPlot[{Range@10}, ColorFunction -> cf]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot3D[
 Table[Sin[j^2 + i], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}],
 Mesh -> None,
 InterpolationOrder -> 0,
 ColorFunction -> cf
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Any reason for the `With[]` filigree (e.g. pedagogical reasons)? `cf = Blend[RGBColor @@@ (dat/255), #] &;` seems to work just as well...

Comment: great postings here! one last question about colorfunctions: when data values ranging from 0 ... 30 and I want to set a maximum for the colorfunction e.g. 0...20 -> all above 20 is colored with the same color (e.g.color3). is this somehow possible to achive ?!

Comment: @J.M. that requires `dat` to remain defined, does it not?  My intention was to create an independent function `cf` without any traps for beginners.  Also, there should be less re-evaluation this way.

Comment: @MrMuh the function `cf` is automatically defined over a range of zero to one.  Arguments higher than one produce the same output value, e.g.: `cf /@ Range[0, 2, 1/3]`.  You probably want to establish your color range outside of the `cf` function itself, that is with the plotting function's options, etc.  Perhaps you would post an additional question about this so it can be addressed more completely?

Comment: @MrMuh: you'll probably want to use `Rescale[]` in conjunction with `Blend[]`, then...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ok i will post it next ... I have forgot to mention that the colorfunction should act like a heatmap, so it should encode the z value

Answer (score 5):

If these are the RGB values of the color scheme:

```
color1 = {229, 245, 249};
color2 = {153, 216, 201};
color3 = {44, 162, 95};
```

you can blend them in this way:

```
Graphics[Table[{Blend[{{0, RGBColor[color1/255]}, {.5, 
 RGBColor[color2/255]}, {1, RGBColor[color3/255]}}, x], 
 Disk[{8 x, 0}]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Since the colors are equispaced, one could use the more compact `Blend[{RGBColor[color1/255], RGBColor[color2/255], RGBColor[color3/255]}, x]` instead.

Comment: awesome work! hm ok maybe you know how to use get the colorfunction into a ListPlot3D?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to make all the color schemes in ColorBrewer available in *Mathematica*:

```
ColorBrewer =
    Association /@ Association[Import["http://colorbrewer2.org/export/colorbrewer.json"] /.
    {s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] :> FromDigits[s], 
     s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, "rgb(*)"] :> Interpreter["Color"][s]} /. 
    v_ /; VectorQ[v, ColorQ] :> With[{cols = v}, Blend[cols, #] &]];
```

Thus, one can now retrieve the color schemes in Wizard's and VLC's answers like so:

```
{ColorBrewer["YlGnBu", 3], ColorBrewer["BuGn", 3]}
```

[image: example]

Comment: I love the streak you are on, getting information from web pages!  For this one, how could I modify it so that I always get the list with the most colors?   For example, compare `{BarLegend[{ColorBrewer["Spectral", 10], {0, 1}}],
 BarLegend[{ColorBrewer["Spectral", 3], {0, 1}}]}` - I would always like the first one.  The maximum number of colors for any given map is different, so I don't want to have to experiment to see that "PuRd" can do 9 colors, but "Spectral" can give 11.

Comment: Hmm, I'll think about it; a hackish method would be to apply `KeySort[]` to all the records of `ColorBrewer` and take the penultimate entry (since the last entry gives the class).

Comment: One could also start with `Import["http://colorbrewer2.org/export/colorbrewer.json", "RawJSON"]`, thus the `Association` muscles get some more training.

Comment: @Karsten, I actually tried that at first, but then it seems the associations become opaque from replacement rules (as I used here); that's why I fell back to normal JSON importing.