# Use selfdefined ColorFunction to encode z dimension with predefined limits

Tags: plotting, color

In my [last question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14743/define-a-color-function-based-on-color-samples-obtained-from-colorbrewer) we defined a colorfunction `cf`. Now I want to use this `ColorFunction` for a number of different plots (`MatrixPlot`, `BarChart3D`, `ListContourPlot` and `ListPlot3D`) as encoding for the `z` value from a given table. For the `ListContourPlot` and `BarChart3D` it seems to work, but I don't know how to apply the color encoding for the remaining plots.

An another problem is the definition of a interval for the color encoding - here I mean that my data ranges from e.g. 0...30 , but i want to define a limit for the `ColorFunction` such that values are encoded from 10...20 according to the `ColorFunction`, values below 10 and over 30 should be clamped to the extrema of the `ColorFunction`. Is it possible to achieve something like that?!

Thanks in advance!

```
dataResponse = {{1, 1, 3.}, {2, 1, 3.5}, {3, 1, 5.5}, {4, 1, 9.}, {5, 1, 13.}, {6, 1,
   30.}, {1, 2, 3.5}, {2, 2, 5.5}, {3, 2, 7.5}, {4, 2, 8.5}, {5, 2, 
  15.}, {6, 2, 30.}, {1, 3, 4.}, {2, 3, 5.5}, {3, 3, 8.5}, {4, 3, 
  10.}, {5, 3, 20.5}, {6, 3, 30.}, {1, 4, 4.5}, {2, 4, 7.5}, {3, 4, 
  12.5}, {4, 4, 30.}, {5, 4, 30.}, {6, 4, 30.}, {1, 5, 5.}, {2, 5, 
  8.}, {3, 5, 14.5}, {4, 5, 30.}, {5, 5, 30.}, {6, 5, 30.}, {1, 6, 
  7.5}, {2, 6, 13.}, {3, 6, 30.}, {4, 6, 30.}, {5, 6, 30.}, {6, 6, 
  30.}}

cbData = {{215, 48, 39},{252, 141, 89},{254, 224, 144}, {224, 243, 248}, {145, 191, 219}, {69, 117, 180}}
cbData = Reverse[cbData]
With[{rgb = RGBColor @@@(cbData/255)},
 cf = Blend[rgb, #]&;
]

ListPlot3D[ dataResponse,
            Mesh -> All, 
            ColorFunction -> cf,
            Boxed -> False,
            FaceGrids -> {
                            {Bottom,{Range[0,5,1],Range[0,5,1]}},
                            {Back,{Range[0,5,1],Range[0,30,5]}},
                            {Left,{Range[0,5,1],Range[0,30,5]}}},
            AspectRatio->1,
            AxesLabel -> {"Scene Complexity","Object Coherence","Response Time"},
            Ticks -> {  {{0,20},{1,30},{2,40},{3,50},{4,60},{5,70}}, {{0,0.045},{1,0.054},{2,0.063},{3,0.072},{4,0.081},{5,0.09}} ,Range[0,30,5]}
            ]
```

As you can see the resulting mesh is color-coded along the y axis, but I want to have the z-axis color encoded and in addition the values from 0...10 should have the same blue and values 20...30 should be red --> so that they are clamped
[image: Mesh]

Comment: What didn't work when you tried using it with `ListContourPlot` or `MatrixPlot`? Please add an example (code) of what you want to do (and what you've tried). From a cursory reading, this looks like something that's adequately covered by the docs on `ColorFunction` and other questions here on the topic.

Comment: Could you give an example of what output you want? `Rescale` is usually helpful when scaling/translating values

Comment: I already mentioned `Rescale[]` in the other post, but it seems to have not been heeded...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start by reading the documentation pages for [`ColorFunctionScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunctionScaling.html) and [`Rescale`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rescale.html).

Then observe this use:

```
cf = ColorData["TemperatureMap"];

ArrayPlot[{Range@40},
 ColorFunction -> (cf@Rescale[#, {20, 30}] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 FrameTicks -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

After understanding this if you still have trouble applying it to a certain plot please ask a specific question including what you have tried.

---

I see from your example that there is another major aspect to your question: the z scale.  Please see the documentation for [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorFunction.html) to see how colors for each axis are defined.  Here is an example:

```
ListPlot3D[
 Table[Sin[j^2 + i] + Mod[i, 6], {i, 0, Pi, Pi/5}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/5}],
 Mesh -> None,
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 InterpolationOrder -> 0,
 ColorFunction -> (cf @ Rescale[#3, {2, 3}] &)
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Pay very close attention to `#3` and be sure to read [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html) and [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) carefully.