# ColorFunction uses graphics coordinates instead of Plot3D coordinates

Tags: plotting, color

I've had the same effect in Mathematica 9 and 10.

I'm trying to color a 3D Plot with another function, let's call it colorFun ( it should highlight the areas where the colorFun is above a certain threshold), but ColorFunction seems to use the wrong coordinates.

Horribly colored minimal example

```
colorFun := Function[{x, y},If[x < y, Red, Blue]]
Plot3D[Evaluate[x^2+y^2],{x,0,1},{y,0,2},ColorFunction->colorFun]
```

[image: Holy cow it's ugly!]

Note that x and y have different intervals plotted, so the divide should not be through the middle. Similar things happen if you change the colorFun to something like y<0.5 .
It seems that the ColorFunction is not using the same coordinates as the function, but rather a kind of normalized version, always going from 0 to 1.

Is this a bug, or is Mathematica beating my ability to understand computers again?

Comment: You actually essentially answered your own questions: the values passed to `ColorFunction` are in fact scaled to [0,1] by default. To avoid that, use `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`.

Comment: Possible duplicates: 
[(6741)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6741/121),
[(6986)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6986/121),
[(14758)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14758/121)

Comment: Please pardon the reopen but I was just about to post an answer when it closed.  If you would still like to close this as a duplicate let me know.  Either way I hope my answer is useful to you.

Comment: I'm fine with keeping it open, if others agree to my impression that your answer help show a new facet of the problem, as compared to the old answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll get a much crisper output if you use Mesh functionality instead:

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2},
  MeshFunctions -> {#/#2 &},
  Mesh -> {{1}}, 
  MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}
]
```

[image]

Or with additional grid lines:

```
Plot3D[x^2 + y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2},
  MeshFunctions -> {#/#2 &, # &, #2 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{1}, 12, 12},
  MeshShading -> {{{Red, Blue}}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: It does look a  lot better. Thanks for teaching cool new stuff!

Answer (score 4):

And immediately after submitting, I find the answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58951/set-the-scale-in-colorfunction):

Using ColorFunctionScaling->False

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[x^2+y^2],{x,0,1},{y,0,2},ColorFunction->colorFun,ColorFunctionScaling->False]
```

Gives the correct coloring. Sorry to bother you all, and thanks for listening!

Decided to keep the question and answer it myself for other who might do the same searches I did, since finding the answer was kinda random for me.