# How to achieve a decent terminator line?

Tags: plotting

What I did:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{z,Cos[z/2]^0.5 Cos[t]/0.6,Cos[z/2]^0.5 Sin[t]*0.6},
{t,-Pi, Pi},{z,-Pi,Pi}, Mesh->None,PlotPoints->50,
PlotRange -> All,Exclusions->None, AxesLabel->{x,y,z},
Lighting -> {{"Directional",RGBColor[1, 1, 1], {-2,1,0}}}]
```

What I got:

[image]

What I want: a decently rendered terminator!

Comment: You have two separate `PlotPoints` specified and only the first (with the lower value) is used.

Comment: Oops, thanks, corrected. Where's a compiler when you need one? :) But still, surely there should be some intra-patch gradation? PlotPoints->big is very costly.

Comment: [Like this?](http://www.dvdtalk.com/reviews/images/reviews/285/full/1436816431_2.jpg) -- Is there another meaning to *Terminator*?

Comment: @MichaelE2 - In astronomy, it is the dividing line between the light and dark part of a planetary body -- and by extension "the dividing line between the light and dark part of an object."

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks.  -- Is the separation supposed to be sharp or fuzzy (as if there were diffraction)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 - the sharpness depends on whether there is an atmosphere involved and the topology of the object relative to the viewpoint.

Comment: @BobHanlon Sure, sorry, I meant that for the OP (to know whether Chris wants a diffuse or sharp border).

Comment: @Michael, if you've seen the "day and night map" question here, that's exactly where a terminator comes in. Another instance would be the various phases of the moon.

Comment: @Michael E2 What I want is diffuse region like this http://i.imgur.com/39JTsAK.png though in this case narrower, due to the brighter lighting.

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YEG9DgRHhA) was a good terminator line.

Comment: Related: [(88319)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88319/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use larger value for `PlotPoints`. What is acceptable is subjective. You will need to experiment to find the smallest value with results that are acceptable to you for whatever your purpose is.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{z, Cos[z/2]^0.5 Cos[t]/0.6, 
  Cos[z/2]^0.5 Sin[t]*0.6}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, Mesh -> None, 
 PlotPoints -> 250, PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", RGBColor[1, 1, 1], {-2, 1, 0}}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping for a solution which was less costly than simply reducing the size of the badly-shaded patches, and which didn't lose the gradation, but if that's as good as it gets, so be it :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

Sharp border:

```
f = {z, Cos[z/2]^(1/2) Cos[t]/0.6, Cos[z/2]^(1/2) Sin[t]*0.6};
ParametricPlot3D[f, {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, u, t, z}, 
    Evaluate@Dot[Cross @@ Transpose@D[f, {{t, z}}], {-2, 1, 0}]]}, 
 Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotStyle -> Specularity[0], 
 MeshShading -> {Black, LightGray}, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Extremely diffuse border, due to the shape of the object, direction of light & lighting model:

```
f = {z, Cos[z/2]^(1/2) Cos[t]/0.6, Cos[z/2]^(1/2) Sin[t]*0.6};
ParametricPlot3D[f, {t, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, MeshFunctions -> {}, 
 PlotStyle -> White, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {-2, 1, 0}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** For what it's worth, here is a model similar to the second plot above, except that is has the default `Specularity` of `ParametricPlot3D`.  It is much faster, due to the use of `Sphere` and `"SpherePoints"`, and has fine resolution of the terminator.

```
Graphics3D[{
  Directive[Specularity[GrayLevel[1], 3], RGBColor[0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051]],
  GeometricTransformation[Sphere[],
   ScalingTransform[
    MaxValue[{#, -Pi <= t <= Pi && -Pi <= z <= Pi}, {t, z}] & /@ Rationalize@f
    ]]},
 PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 Lighting -> {{"Directional", White, {-2, 1, 0}}}, 
 Method -> {"SpherePoints" -> 500}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I was looking to retain diffusion. Thanks for option #2, but its apparent improvement is just the result of you dropping the specularity and thereby spreading the diffusion. With specularity restored, the result is actually worse: http://i.imgur.com/DssUOmP.png .

Comment: @Chris Oh well, I didn't appreciate the effect of specularity, nor was it clear that it was required.  If it's exactly this shape or something very close to it, then it might be possible to do to improve it.  The 250-PlotPoint graphics are still pretty ragged.  But I don't want to waste my time, if it's not going to be any help.

Comment: Out of interest, what's the advantage of your move of ParametricPlot3D's parameter #1 into f?

Comment: "in the gradient computed in MeshFunction" Ah, I missed that. Thanks.

Comment: "It is much faster" Agreed. I used ParametricPlot3D because in general I need a paramteric plot. "has the default Specularity of ParametricPlot3D" How did you discover that default? Can code inspect the value? The docs tell me only "Automatic".

Comment: @ChrisJJ `Cases[plot, _Specularity | _RGBColor, Infinity]` or ``Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", ParametricPlot3D]``

Comment: @Michael #1 fails http://i.imgur.com/kQXW1b6.png #2 succeeds http://i.imgur.com/gs5ZSd8.png . Thanks!

Comment: Michael, maybe *someone* should :-) Because the definition affects the result, which I think is failing to show the *default*. e.g. http://i.imgur.com/jy2DI0d.png

Comment: @ChrisJJ Why not simply `ParametricPlot3D[{}, {u, 0, 1}]`?  In a way the one-independent-variable form is really a different function, a homonym, and such ambiguity might cause confusion when one ignores the context.  We were talking about **your plot** after all. :-) (BTW, your example does show the default for the homonym, although you'd find out more if you executed `Cases[plot, _RGBColor | _AbsoluteThickness, Infinity]`.)

Comment: 1) Becasue that fails http://i.imgur.com/zuwHRjk.png 2) No I wasn't talking about my plot. I was taking about the default.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I didn't make my point clearly enough, I guess: There are **two** distinct functions,1D and 2D (each embedded in 3D, of course) and naturally **two** distinct defaults. Correspondingly there are **two** `Cases` commands. You have to use the right `Cases` command or you'll fail to reveal the default.

Comment: I'm failing to understand this. Not helped by the fact that at least one of your comments seems now missing (it was before my "Michael, maybe someone should"). I'll write a new question. Thanks for your help.