# Replicate $\LaTeX$ PGF colormap/hot to Mathematica color scheme

Tags: color, customization

I want to replicate the color scheme `colormap/hot` from $\LaTeX$ PGF's package [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en). The [color scheme `colormap/hot` can be found on p. 189](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=189) in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#). It is defined by

```
\pgfplotsset{
colormap={hot}{color(0cm)=(blue); color(1cm)=(yellow); color(2cm)=(orange); color(3cm)=(red)}
}
```

The named colors are from the $\LaTeX$ package [`xcolor`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor), the [manual has a table of named base colors in section 4.1](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf#page=38) and additional information, if needed.

The relevant definitions fo the used colors are from the [`xcolor.sty`](http://www.olos.de/~ukern/tex/xcolor/tex/xcolor.sty.gz) file:

```
\definecolorset{rgb/hsb/cmyk/gray}{}{}{
  blue,0,0,1/.66667,1,1/1,1,0,0/.11;
  yellow,0,0,1,0/1,1,0/.16667,1,1/.89;
  orange,1,.5,0/.083333,1,1/0,.5,1,0/.595;
  red,1,0,0/0,1,1/0,1,1,0/.3}
```

The RGB values are as expected. I think the different colors are blended in a linear fashion.

I want to have a new color scheme, which replicates the above mentioned colormap. If this is not possible, an existing color scheme can be modified. I tried this myself, but could not get a working `ColorDataFunction` object. With the `ColorBar` package I was not able to define the color scheme manually, without having to drag control points in the form.

I got as far as this:

```
ColorData["TemperatureMap"] // FullForm
(* ColorDataFunction["TemperatureMap","Gradients",List[0,1],Function[Blend["TemperatureMap",Slot[1]]]] *)

colfunc=ColorDataFunction["PGFhot", "Gradients", List[0, 1], Blend[Transpose[{{0, 1/3, 2/3, 1}, {Blue, Yellow, Orange, Red}}], #1] &]
```

But `colfunc` is apparently no `ColorDataFunction`.

In the end, I want to use the new color scheme like this:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{ColorData["Rainbow"], {0, 1}}]
]
```

Comment: Similar: 
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22086/define-a-color-function-using-piecewise
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14743/define-a-color-function-based-on-color-samples-obtained-from-colorbrewer
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57885/is-it-possible-to-insert-new-colour-schemes-into-colordata

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    colfunc = Blend[Transpose[{{0, 1/3, 2/3, 1}, {Blue, Yellow, Orange, Red}}], #]&

    Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> colfunc, PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{colfunc, {0, 1}}]]
```

[image]

This is how to simply use a custom color scheme. If you're wanting to have it integrated into MMA in a manner similar to the built in `ColorDataFunction`s then [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57885/is-it-possible-to-insert-new-colour-schemes-into-colordata) is a good question to read through.

Comment: Thank you. I also tried you definition of `colfunc`, but I did not name it and tried to use it as a pure function. But I forgot the pair of curly brackets so it would not work.

Comment: Due to the equal spacing, `Blend[{Blue, Yellow, Orange, Red}, #] &` will also work.